# Autonumbers not generated sequentially

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

One of my table contains a autonumber feild  ShiftPk ,Which iam using as primary key for that table,But when I inserted values to the record the primary key generated are not the sequential ones

I know autonumber neednot be always sequential but all my other auto numbers are working in sequential order Please find my script below and advice if any issue is from my part

```
   ****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ShiftMasterNew_tbl]    Script Date: 03/09/2013 13:21:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShiftMasterNew_tbl](
    [ShiftPK] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ShiftName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Duration] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ShiftMasterNew_tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ShiftPK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_ShiftMasterNew_tbl] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ShiftName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

What make this tabel autonumber different from others

Comment: `IDENTITY` produces **sequential numbers** - the next one is always bigger than the previous one - but it makes **no guarantee** that these numbers are without any gaps between them. There can be gaps - so what? It's important that the numbers are indeed ever increasing - anything else is not relevant.

Comment: Well the increment is set to `1` so they ought to be generated sequentially. Gaps you are seeing may be due to failed (rolled back) inserts or deleted rows. On 2012 gaps may also emerge [after server restart](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity) Why does it matter? You can't rely on `IDENTITY` values being sequential.

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/03/10/How-to-efficiently-reuse-gaps-in-identity-column.aspx

Comment: If an insert fails (say attempting to insert a `NULL` to a non-nullable column), the number will increment but the row will not be inserted. Next time you insert, the number increments _again_, but you will have a gap. The system works as designed.

Comment: thanks frnds ..but What iam curious is i feel that the time delay i make in making an insert is also having some impact....I know its a wild thought but its look like that...when i took 2 minutes to enter the a rec0rd after the previous insertion the next shiftpk is incremented by two , when i took 5 mnts its incremented by 5....its a scenaio i watched may be due to my over excitement on issue

Comment: Are you sure you're the only one to modify the table? The SQL profiler could tell you. Also, there might be a trigger or a sql agent job which confuses the counter.  Also, in seems as if you 'feel' that something is wrong. Try to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out the issue ..Any failed Try to insert is also consuming an identifier

for example if I  inserted 
1 
2
3
and then had a failed insert

then if I inserted next its identifier is

5

Answer (score 0):

How is the data inserted in to the table? I suspect if you have gaps in your identity column so for example it looks like the following:

```
1
2
5
6
8
9
10
15
```

...this probably is a symptom that something is going astray when the data is being inserted into the table. Can you add any further information on the update process to your `OP` ?

As the comments have said - it will definitely be **SEQUENTIAL** but there may be gaps. If you need to prove to yourself that they are sequential can you add in a DateTime field such as "WhenUpdated"?